# Block system partitions set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $B$ be a block of a set $X$ under the operation of a group $G$. Let $GB=\bigcup_{g\in G}gB$. Then, is $(gB)_{g\in G}$ the associated partition of $X$, or is it $(Y)_{Y\in GB}$? This concerns the proof of disjointness. If the former is the partition, then I have to show $g\ne g'$ implies $gB\cap g'B=\emptyset$. If the latter is the partition, then I have to show that $gB\ne g'B$ implies $gB\cap g'B=\emptyset$. So, which is it?

Comment: First, you might want to assume your group is transitive, otherwise the images of the block might not cover the set. (Blocks are usually mostly studied for transitive groups.) Second, in that case, isn't $GB$ just $X$?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. The partition is $\{ gB : g \in G \}$, and to prove that it's a partition you have to prove that $gB \ne gB' \Rightarrow gB \cap g'B = \emptyset$.

Comment: Aren't $GB:=\{gB\mid g\in G\}$ and $\{Y\mid Y\in GB\}$ the same set of subsets? Or are you using round parentheses instead of curly braces in the notation $(gB){g\in G}$ to indicate some kind of ordering or multiplicity, in which case - why?